# visual studio generate test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

is there any vs addins that can take a class and set up all the wiring to generate the test class and methods as well as mocking the dependencies, etc.  this seems like something that can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft tried something like that awhile back, I believe, and was widely criticized for not understanding what [Test-Driven Development/Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) was all about.

[Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) might be part of what you're looking for. It's an aid to unit testing, not a replacement for it.

There are also IoC Container frameworks (and I think mock/isolation frameworks as well) that support [auto mocking](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/02/03/auto-mocking-explained.aspx), which might also help.

As Vadim mentioned, templates and snippets can take care of a lot of the boilerplate code.

I haven't used Pex or auto mocking; I just do what Vadim does.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create some VS templates.

I've create some Resharper templates for mysel but they are as sophisticated as what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not; even if the sigs can be automated, You'll need to provide all the cases; it can't infer what is supposed to equal what, what properties matter, what are the edge cases, etc.